# References for Integer Programming

Tags: reference-request, integer-programming

I could not find any questions on the site about references for Integer Programming, so hopefully this is not a duplicate. 
I am taking a graduate course on Integer Programming this semester and the textbook for the course is the one by [Wolsey](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471283665). The book isn't available in our library and it costs upwards of 100$ on Amazon and I wanted to know if there are any other books which cover similar material. Thanks.